# Javascript serviceworker: Processing & resending body of request

Tags: javascript, service-worker, fetch-api

I want to use a Javascript serviceworker to log outgoing requests. My current approach is this:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

    var req = new Request("https://example.com?url=" + encodeURI(event.request.url), {
        method: event.request.method,
        headers: event.request.headers,
        body: event.request.body
    });

    fetch(req);
});
```

This works fine for GET requests, but it doesn't work for the `body` of POST/PUT requests. I tried using `body: event.request.body.blob()`, but that did not work either.

Is there a simple way to access the body of a fetched request in serviceworkers and resend it elsewhere?

Comment: `event.request.body` is a `ReadableStream`, so it should be fine to pass to `Request` as you've tried. But don't expect `.blob()` to work, `ReadableStream`s don't have such a method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  const requestClone = event.request.clone();

  event.respondWith(
    (async function () {
      const params = await requestClone.json().catch((err) => err);

      if (params instanceof Error) {
        // this is a simple check, but handle errors appropriately
      }

      if (event.request.method === "POST") {
        console.log(`POST request with params: ${params}`);
        // do work here
      }
      return fetch(event.request);
    })()
  );
});
```

Note that you have to create a clone for the `event.request` to be able to call the `text` method on it because the request is a stream and can only be consumed once, so you'd run into issues if you tried to grab the request's params and then use it for something else.

Also, you could use any of the following methods to retrieve the body from a request, so use whatever is appropriate:

- `event.request.arrayBuffer()`
- `event.request.blob()`
- `event.request.json()`
- `event.request.text()`
- `event.request.formData()`

Assuming the above code snippet is included in your `ServiceWorker` file, the following example would give you what you need:

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ title: "foo", body: "bar", userId: 1 }),
  headers: { "Content-Type": `application/json` },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(`fetch response`, json))
  .catch((error) => console.error(`fetch error`, error));

// console logs
//  >> POST request with {"title":"foo","body":"bar","userId":1} (worker.js)
//  >> fetch response {title: "foo", body: "bar", userId: 1, id: 101} (index.js)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had hoped that it would also be possible to access requests performed via a `<form>` tag this way, but that doesn't seem to be the case. URLs visited in the browser are logged, as are requests performed via `fetch`/`XMLHttpRequest` or via `<img>` tag, but not via `<form>`.

Comment: @tim `form`s with `action`s work a little different than `AJAX` requests - you could just intercept that form submission with `JavaScript` and make the request using `fetch` so that you can utilize `service workers`

Comment: What surprised me was that visiting URLs in the browser & img requests can also be intercepted, so it doesn't seem to be *just* AJAX requests. It seems that what I wanted to do isn't going to work, but I still learned something, so thanks!